# DB storage of values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, database-design

I'm just looking to get different people's opinions because for some reason I'm not looking in the right places but what do most people use or better yet what is the most accepted away of storing something in a database with either an active value or inactive value. I was thinking of having a database table for statuses and the first one would be Active and the other Inactive and then I have an form when creating a new content page or something and have a select dropdown of values of active(1) or inactive(2) and store 1 or 2 as the status_id for that content page.

Is that the best way or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the database you use and what data types it supports. If it has a built-in type for `Boolean` values I would use that, otherwise I would use a `char(1)` with a `check constraint` that checks for the allowed values (`0`/`1` or `n`/`y`) because it's faster than any other type out there and it does the job.

In case you have multiple boolean flags (that are related, but not necessary) and don't need support for NULL (which is a third state) on a per flag basis I would go for a `numeric` column with bit flags if your database supports that (`1=true` and `0=false`, bit one for flag one, bit two for the second flag and so on).
Mysql has very good support for bit operations, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html).

Answer (score 3):

I usually just use a Boolean. 0 is Inactive and 1 is active.

Comment: Do you think I should even have a separate table for statuses and have a dropdown or do you believe there's a better way?

Comment: It depends on the schema. For something like an options table I would just have a column 'status' and then you can just loop through the result set and have foreach (rows in resultset) { if(status = 1) { do stuff } }

Answer (score 1):

you can use boolean as well as enum('Active','Inactive') for the same